# how to align Angular Material mdAutoComplete with other components in a row?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm working with **Angular material 1.1.0** and **Angular 1.5**. I'm trying to put an auto complete next to a multi-select input withing a row which defines an alignment as `layout-align="start center"`but the elements are not align. Here is a [pen](http://codepen.io/kevinbarrientos/pen/yJmExO) where the **yellow div** shows the issue.

At the bottom of the pen's css there is a commented style that can fix the problem by removing the extra space that the elements create to show error output. But this makes the autocomplete loading bar to be out of place.

I could simply align the elements as the **white div** as `layout-align="start start"` but this will left too much space between components as shown in the example.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: If you remove `layout-padding layout-align="start center"` this and `start start` as well both the lines are aligned in a row.

Comment: @Rakeschand but this makes the **search** button to grow. How can I handle that?

Comment: why don't you put your button in a div of `flex="25"` or any fixed length

Comment: @Rakeschand thaks for the reply. It is as well another way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the CSS below - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/EgYyyo?editors=1100)

CSS

```
#myAutocomplete {
  height: 85px;
}
```

Markup

```
<md-autocomplete ... id="myAutocomplete">
```

Comment: Thanks. But this makes the autocomplete loading bar to be out of place again.

Comment: @ingkevin Yeah, didn't notice that. Good question, by the way.